# How to remove specific file types (i.e. docx) from multiple specific Sharepoint libaries?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell, delete

I am a newbie when it comes to Powershell so I'm asking for help. In Sharepoint 2010 I have several document libraries in a single site collection that all start with the name of 'PT-' and in those libraries are specific files that I need to delete like *.xyz. How can I loop through the libraries and remove the files based on the file extension using Powershell?

Any help would be appreciated and let me know if I need to supply more information.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the below code, I have not done test run of the below code because now I dont have powershell. You can just grasp the logic and idea to achive your requirement using the below code.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$siteURL = "Your Site URL" 
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL) 
$count=0;
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{ 
    $listCounter = $web.Lists.Count 
    for($i=0;$i -le $listCounter;$i++) 
    {  
        $list = $web.Lists[$i] 
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") { 
        $newList = $web.Lists.item($list.ID);
    $collListItems = $newList.Items; 
        Write-Host $newList
        Write-Host "*********************"
    $countt = $collListItems.Count 
    Write-Host  $countt
    for($intIndex = $countt; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--) 
    {
    if($collListItems[$intIndex].Name)
    {
        if($collListItems[$intIndex].Name.Contains(".your file extension"))
        {
         Write-Host  $collListItems[$intIndex].Name
         $collListItems[$intIndex].Delete()

        }
     }      

    }     

        }
    }
    Write-Host "-----------------------"
    }
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

The above code will loop through all the Document libraries, displays and deletes the specified file.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting to understand what are trying to do but something is off. With your code starting with    $countt = $collListItems.Count - 1 it looks like you got the total number of items in the library and are going to traverse it and delete it based on extension however I don't see where $item.name would be assigned to an item in the library. At this point it comes across as a null value and errors out. 

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, in document libraries, "Name" field is mandatory for all the items in the library, so we will not face null exception. Now I have altered the code, you can make use of it.

Comment: Karthik, I really appreciate your help with this. This made my life a ton easier. Thanks!